# Exclude specific browsers (Puffin and Photon) from HTTP/HTTPS rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mobile, browser, https

So my site is going secure. Except one directory (/da) has old Flash content (that I cannot edit) that simply refuses to work under SSL. So, I pieced a few StackOverflow user solutions (THANK YOU!) together, wrote a HTTP --> HTTPS rewrite where I carve out an exception for the /da directory and got that much working just fine.

The only issue is with mobile browsers which play Flash content (such as Puffin and Photon). For some reason, they don't like the rewrite code and continue to open the /da directory under HTTPS... thus the Flash content doesn't work.

I thought that I could just exclude those browsers from the rewrite, but I can't get that piece to work. Please see below and let me know what I'm doing wrong. It's the "Puffin|BonEcho" line which I'm trying to get to work. Am I doing it wrong?

Or is there a better solution? Is there a way to get Puffin and Photon to comply with the HTTP/HTTPS rewrite script?

Thanks!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]

# Force HTTPS for anything which isn't /da
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s/da [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"Puffin|BonEcho" [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(da) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

# Force HTTP for anything which is /da
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]+\s/da [NC]
RewriteRule !^da https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

# Remove index.php from URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1
```